# Zoom quits unexpectedly when I screen share, I'm on POP OS and investigating

Tags: pop-os, zoom

I have this issue with Zoom that it quits unexpectedly every time I screen share, especially when I am in an organization called Microverse and calling my colleagues. I sent to Zoom support and they said to investigate everywhere.

Anybody using POP OS having similar issue? I have updated Zoom and it still happens, just not all the time. Soon I would need to use Zoom extensively for meetings with my organization Microverse so a fraction of time it quits unexpectedly when I screen share is not acceptable.

Any pointers?

Thanks,

Currently I'm on Zoom 5.15, .deb packaged for Ubuntu downloaded from their website, installed via Eddy. Xorg.